# Assign category to entry using a plugin

Tags: categories, entry, saveentry

Feel like I'm going crazy here...

I've got this snippet of code.

I find my entry based on title key/value.

I find my category ids based on alcohol key/value.

I attempt to set the entry category relation and save.

I get no errors. But nothing is saved either.

I've found other similar questions but nothing is working.

Need a fresh pair of eyes...

```
    $entriesWithAlcohol = [
                [
                    'title' => 'Jupiter Hotel + NEXT',
                    'alcohol' => ['byo', 'byo-with-corkage-fee'],
                ],
            ];
    
            foreach ($entriesWithAlcohol as $entryWithAlcohol) {
                $entry = \craft\elements\Entry::find()->title(\craft\helpers\Db::escapeParam($entryWithAlcohol['title']))->one();
    
                if ($entry) {
                    $categoryIds = [];
    
                    foreach ($entryWithAlcohol['alcohol'] as $alcoholValue) {
                        $category = \craft\elements\Category::find()->slug(\craft\helpers\Db::escapeParam($alcoholValue))->one();
    
                        if ($category) {
                            $categoryIds[] = $category->id;
                        }
                    }
    
                    $entry->setFieldValue('alcoholWip', $categoryIds);
    
                    if (Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry)) {
                        Craft::info('Entry updated (ID: '.$entry->id.').');
                    } else {
                        Craft::error('Could not updated the entry (ID: '.$entry->id.').', LogLevel::Error);
                    }
                }
    
                //Craft::dd($entry->alcoholWip);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$entry->setFieldValue('alcoholWip', array_values($categoryIds));
```

Forgot to use `array_values` to pass in the values only, not the key/value pairs.

See, I told you I was going crazy!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Hi from PDX! 